# Onclick not firing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, button, event-handling

I have a set of buttons on my master page (I have attached the code below) but no onclick event is being raised. I pulled the final page source and no onclick event was present. As you can see I tried a few different approaches to solve the problem. I am looking for a normal postback to the server but I am getting nothing when I click any of these buttons.

What am I not doing?

--Master

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" CssClass="btn" runat="server" OnClick ="Button_Click" />
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" CssClass="btn" CommandArgument="1" CommandName="ButtonPress" runat="server" OnClick="Button_Click" />
<asp:Button ID="btnClear" CssClass="btn" CommandArgument="8" CommandName="ButtonPress" runat="server" OnCommand="Button_Command" />
<asp:Button ID="btnCancel" CssClass="btn" CommandArgument="4" CommandName="ButtonPress" runat="server" OnCommand="Button_Command" />
```

--Master Code Behind

```
Protected Sub Button_Command(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As CommandEventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Command, btnClear.Command
    Session("ButtonClicked") = e.CommandArgument
End Sub

Protected Sub Button_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click, btnSubmit.Click
    Session("ButtonClicked") = CType(sender, Button).CommandArgument
End Sub
```

--Page Source

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$btnSubmit" value="Submit" id="ctl00_btnSubmit" class="btn" />
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$btnSave" value="Save" id="ctl00_btnSave" class="btn" /> 
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$btnClear" value="Clear" id="ctl00_btnClear" class="btn" />
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$btnCancel" value="Cancel" id="ctl00_btnCancel" class="btn" />
```

Comment: What happens if you strip out all the "onClick" and "onCommand" attributes from the master page, and just use the "Handles" clause on the codebehind? It looks like all of your buttons are explicitly defining their events, which isn't usual (though it should still work).

Comment: That doesn't work. The only way I can get it to fire is to set the PostBackURL property. But even when it fired it raises a JS runtime error saying that 'theForm' is undefined. theForm seems to be the name .Net assigns to the form but yet it doesn't seem to see it.

Comment: Are you sure you have a `<form runat="server">` tag? Are the buttons inside it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the issue. Here was the problem. On the master Page I had to change this:

`< script language="javascript" src="scriptLibrary.js" type="text/javascript"/>`

To this:

`< script language="javascript" src="scriptLibrary.js" type="text/javascript">< /script>`

And after that it performed a normal postback without errors.