# asp.net Button OnClick event not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have problem in asp.net button control.

I define a button in form, `onclick` event of button is not firing when I click on the button.

```
<asp:Button ID="btn_QuaSave" runat="server" Text="SAVE" OnClick="btn_QuaSave_Click" /> 

protected void btn_QuaSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669448/onclick-not-firing

Comment: How do you know the event is not firing?

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint

Comment: check the CausesValidation property of your button. set it to False if its true. Also check your asp.net page code file link is exactly same in which you have put the event.

Comment: Is the button inside a template control (such as an `<asp:Repeater>` or `<asp:GridView>`)?

Comment: no inside ajax panel content control

Comment: None of them worked unfortunately for me...:/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you copied this method from other page/application ? if yes then it will not work, So you need to delete the event and event name assigned to the button then go to design and go to button even properties go to onClick event double click next to it, it will generate event and it automatically assigns event name to the button.
this should work

Comment: i not copy it from other page

Comment: I ended up reading your answer and deciding to move the page, create a new one named the same and manually move the markup and code behind.  Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 39):

Because your button is in `control` it could be that there is a validation from another control that don't allow the button to submit.
The result in my case was to add `CausesValidation` property to the button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btn_QuaSave" runat="server" Text="SAVE" OnClick="btn_QuaSave_Click" CausesValidation="False"/>
```

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem, my aspnet button's click was not firing. It turns out that some where on other part of the page has an input with html "required" attribute on.

This might be sound strange, but once I remove the required attribute, the button just works normally.

Comment: so weird. This error made me compose my code all over again. Still the same. Thank you for this tip. Had to commend you sir.

Comment: if you can ignore required fields put CausesValidation="false" in your asp:button

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar issue and none of the answers worked for me. Maybe someone finds my solution helpful. In case you do not mind submitting on button click, only attaching to click event setting `UseSubmitBehavior="false"` may be worth trying.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using updatepanel on onclick event, this may happen.

Use 'EnableEventValidation="false"'  in your page markup like this :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/ars_home.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Transaction_Window.aspx.cs" Inherits="Transaction_Window" EnableEventValidation="false" %>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

In my case I put **required="required"** inside **CKEditor** control.
Removing this attribute fixed the issue.
**Before**

```
<CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="txtDescription" BasePath="/ckeditor/" runat="server" required="required"></CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
```

**After**

```
<CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="txtDescription" BasePath="/ckeditor/" runat="server"></CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
```

Comment: Yup, someone stuck a required in the aspx.

Comment: @SixOThree You know, Your comment is actually the answer! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Try to go into Design mode in Visual Studio, locate the button and double click the button that should setup the event. Otherwise once the button is selected in Design more, go to the properties and try setting it from there.

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem did all changed the button and all above mentioned methods then I did a simple thing I was using two forms on a single page and form with in the form so I removed one and it worked :)

Comment: That worked for me. In my case, the template i downloaded had a form element which i removed.

Answer (score 1):

Try to `Clean` your solution and then try once again.

It will definitely work. Because every thing in code seems to be ok.

Go through this link for cleaning solution>

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/e53aab69-75b9-434a-bde3-74ca0865c165/

Answer (score 1):

Add validation groups for your validator elements. This allows you distinguish between different groups which to include in validation. Add validation group also to your submit button

Answer (score 1):

in my case:
make sure not exist any form element in your page other than top main form,
this cause events not fired

Answer (score 1):

If the asp button is inside `<a href="#"> </a>` tag then also the `Click` event will not raise.

Hope it's useful to some one.

Comment: That is the magic! I was trying to invoke a login form from a modal popup using JqueryModal. Pulled it out and boom! It worked. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of nesting the LinkButton within a **Repeater** you must using something similar to the following:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="MyUpdate">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>

 protected void Repeater1_OnItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
 {
    if (e.CommandName.Equals("MyUpdate"))
    {
        // some code
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's throwing no error but still not firing the click event when you click the submit button, try to add `action="YourPage.aspx"` to  your form.

Answer (score 0):

Even i had two forms one for desktop view and other for mobile view , Removed one formed worked for me . I dint knew asp.page should have only one form.

Answer (score 0):

Try this onserverclick

```
<button id ="DemoButton" runat="server" onserverclick="button_Click">Login</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by replacing the onclick event to onserverclick and it worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).