# ASP.NET button not firing on click event

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, button

I am new to Asp.net and my question may not be so professional. I am using the design of [Udemy.com](http://udemy.com) in my asp.net web forms project. I put the header and footer of `udemy` in a `masterpage`. But when I add a button to one of m web forms the click event will not fire.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click1" Text="Button" />

protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Title = "Sample Text";
}
```

To fix this problem, I deleted all of the scripts from my pages. Also I tried to set `CausesValidation` to False. But nothing helps.
Could you help me fix this problem?

#### Update

I added the OnClick event to my code. But I still face that problem.

Comment: First find out Google, then ask here , take and learn here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: you did not add OnClick="Button1_Click in your asp code.

Comment: Open your browser's javascript console and see if there's any errors when you click the button.

Answer (score 14):

All the previous answers are correct, except that you "already added" the OnClick event to the 
".aspx" file.
I don't know whether it is something in the template you're using, or somewhere else in the code. But I would recommend that you check the following (Based on my experience in being stuck in similar situations):

1. Do you have any Field Validators in your ".aspx" page? Perhaps one of those validators are fired and if they were without any Error Messages.
2. Have you copied that button from somewhere else? If yes, then try to add a new button and add its click event, by double clicking the button in the design mode. As sometimes the "OnClick" button's event is not registered on the ".designer.cs" file.

Comment: I had field validators which came from somewhere else... they had display set as none ¬¬ Thanks! And I feel stupid

Comment: If you have hidden fields with validators, then again this issue could occur.  I found a similar situation where I've hide the rows like this with validator fields. <tr style="display: none;">.  Removing / assigning default values to the fields, fixed the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Some points you may try... The code that you posted (after update) should work.

- If you open the Design part of your visual studio and double click in the button, This will lead you to the event click of that button, if there is not one event, then it'll create one for you.
- Your button must be within the form tag.
- To test the event click is firing, use `Breakpoints` not label or any other markup change, but if you want it ... you should check if the `Title` component has `runat="server"` attribute and it's within an update panel.

Comment: Though not solved my problem, I would never think about using the design part to check if the event is right or not

Answer (score 4):

This is a sample code , You have missed "OnClick="MyButton_Click" in your button.

aspx

```
<asp:Button ID="MyButton" **OnClick="MyButton_Click"** runat="server" />
code behind

protected void **MyButton_Click**(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Put code here over there chuhu
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `CausesValidation = "false"` attribute of button like:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" CausesValidation="false"></asp:Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `OnClick="Button1_Click"`.
You need to add event like this

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click"></asp:Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are assigning the click handler in code behind, make sure that it is not inside an IsPostBack == false check :

```
void Page_Load (object oSender, EventArgs oEventArgs)
{
   if (IsPostBack == false)
   {
       oButton += new EventHandler(oButton_Click); // does not work
   }
   oButton += new EventHandler(oButton_Click); // does work
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your button should be like this

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onClick="Button1_Click" />
```

You are not mentioning the event handler for the button click event.

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click"></asp:Button>
```

Is this your **page directive**?

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to place Button within form tag

as

```
<form id="#" runat="Server">
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click"></asp:Button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Page directive like this

**Default.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

**HTML**

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
```

the following code should be inside the **Default.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.Title = "Sample Text";
    }
```

My guess of where might be the problem is there may be problem in the **directive**

**Default.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

or else you wouldn't have called the ***asp:Button*** tag inside the **form** tag

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />

    </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample code , You have missed "OnClick="MyButton_Click" in your button.

aspx

```
<asp:Button ID="MyButton" **OnClick="MyButton_Click"** runat="server" />
```

code behind

```
protected void **MyButton_Click**(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Put code here
}
```

My personal answer is, You need to learn more things in Google

Some best tutorials for asp.net

http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/default.asp

http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials

http://asp.net-tutorials.com/

http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/default.aspx and  can learn lot of knowledge from [MSDN website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/aa336522.aspx)

You can understand more asp.net controls and etc....

Answer (score 0):

Please check button is define properly in yourpage.aspx.designer.cs file.

something like below code:

```
protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button Button1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Test the simple example in online [aspdotnetfiddle](http://aspdotnetfiddle.com/XMQ3B).

Created sample program with single button & label control, when click on button, firing click event of button, in that assigning label text value.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it wasn't firing the event because I was appending the button to the body of the master page and the `<form>` tag was in the `<body>` tag

I've solved the issue by appending the button to the `<form>` tag

## Old code

```
$('body').append($(".ButtonsDiv"));
```

## New code

```
$('#form1').append($(".ButtonsDiv"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have two buttons and two validation summaries, you must add `ValidationGroup = "Group2"` for each validiation summary, textbox and button.

And for the other add: `ValidationGroup="Group1"`, it should work then.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is validation firing and your button shouldn't trigger validation, consider adding CausesValidation="false" to the attributes of your button.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript can fail silently on your page, causing processing to be abandoned which prevents the click event from firing. 
If I suspect this is happening, I paste this immediately under the script tag before debugging:

```
window.onerror = function (message, filename, linenumber) {
        alert("JS error: " + message + " on line " + linenumber + " for " + filename);
}
```

Remove for production code.

Answer (score 0):

Check and try remove the attribute "required" on other input element. 
it works with in my case.. 
it took me while to find it out.

Read here this question also..same issue 
[asp.net Button OnClick event not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15569857/asp-net-button-onclick-event-not-firing)