# Why does the button not fire a click event

Tags: c#, asp.net

Following is my code. 
It's not giving me desired result. I can't understand what is the problem here. Please tell me what's wrong here. The click event for btnbookavil is not being fired and there is no error in output

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LibraryConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("bookinsertion", con);
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idnumber",txtid.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtname.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", txtyear.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@department", txtdepart.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bookname", txtbook.Text);           
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();       
    con.Close();
    Response.Redirect("~/LendingForm2.aspx");
}
protected void btnbookavail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("availablebooks", con);
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bookname", txtbook.Text);
    SqlParameter output=new SqlParameter();
    output.ParameterName="@BooksAvailable";
    output.SqlDbType=System.Data.SqlDbType.Int;
    output.Direction=System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(output);          
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    string bookavail = output.Value.ToString();
    if (Convert.ToInt32(bookavail) != 0 && Convert.ToInt32(bookavail) > 0)
    {
        lblbookavail.Visible = true;
        lblbookavail.Text = bookavail + "books are available";
    }
    else
    {
        lblbookavail.Text = "No books available";
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using break points and see if the control goes inside your _click block? can you give the design page code for your button?

Comment: yes I tried using break point but the control is not going inside it

Comment: can you show the aspx code of button. and are there any validation controls being used?

Comment: and see the solutions here. It's a possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20798135/asp-net-button-not-firing-on-click-event

Comment: can you please tell me tha

Comment: there is no onclick event in the aspx page for that button. now i am getting the result. thank you

Comment: I m glad it helped. mark my edited answer as answer if it helped ya :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't say much without understanding entire problem. But if by no error in output you mean you are not getting the error message in case there is no book available, I suggest set the visibility of your control true as it appears that its not visible and gets visible only if books are available. So in case book is not found, you set the text property of your label to "No books available" butyou don't set its visibility true. So make your label visible irrespective of result.

```
lblbookavail.Visible = true;
if (Convert.ToInt32(bookavail) != 0 && Convert.ToInt32(bookavail) > 0)
       {           
           lblbookavail.Text = bookavail + "books are available";
       }
       else
       {
           lblbookavail.Text = "No books available";
       }
```

also check if there is an `onclick` event specified in your button. and any `CausesValidation` set to true. If there is assign it false.
Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20798135/asp-net-button-not-firing-on-click-event)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, just maybe , the name of the button from designer properties does not match with the name you have it in code behind , verify that.

Comment: @Ovy.Istarate,Use comments for suggetions.