# C# Dynamic button not firing click event

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, button, click

It reloads the page empty when I click the button. How do I fire click event on button click? I think Page.IsPostBack is the reason it reloads the page empty instead of showing the label.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
            {
                account account = new account();
                accountManager accountManager = new accountManager();
                group group = new group();
                groupManager groupManager = new groupManager();
                string emailAddress;

                emailAddress = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
                account = accountManager.getAccInfoByEmailAddress(emailAddress);
                group = groupManager.getGroupLeader(account.groupNo);

                if (account.groupNo == 0)
                {
                    divMessage.InnerHtml = "You are not in any group.";
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Button btn = new Button();
                        btn.Text = "Click";
                        btn.Click += new EventHandler(button_Click);
                        form1.Controls.Add(btn);
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        divMessage.InnerHtml = "Unable to retrieve data. Please contact administrator if the problem persists.";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

.

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label Label1 = new Label();
            Label1.Text = "rthfg";
            form1.Controls.Add(Label1);
        }
```

Comment: after you click the button the page is going to be a postback so just create your button outside of the if(!IsPostBack)

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET button not firing on click event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20798135/asp-net-button-not-firing-on-click-event)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click the button, or somehow else generate a postback, ASP.NET creates the page (as it always does) and tries to find the source of the request, that is the button you clicked. In your case this button is no longer on the page, so ASP.NET cannot find anything, end does not fire the event.

Resolution seems easy enough in your case - just always create the button and put it on the page, regardless of the postback:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
...
}

Button btn = new Button();
btn.Text = "Click";
btn.Click += new EventHandler(button_Click);
form1.Controls.Add(btn);
```

Btw, why make the button dynamic? Dynamic controls are always harder to manage.