# Values from textBox not getting inserted into database C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, insert, addition

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Request.InputStream.Length > 0)
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream))
                {
                    string hexString = Server.UrlEncode(reader.ReadToEnd());
                    string imageName = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yy hh-mm-ss");
                    string imagePath = string.Format("~/losefound/{0}.png", imageName);
                    string ItemName = txtItemName.Text;
                    string Place = txtPlace.Text;
                    byte[] bytes = ConvertHexToBytes(hexString);
                    File.WriteAllBytes(Server.MapPath(imagePath), bytes);
                    string VisitorManagementConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["VisitorManagementConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(VisitorManagementConnectionString))
                    {
                        string query = "INSERT INTO LostFound (ItemName, FoundAt, TimeIn, ImageName, ContentType, Data) VALUES(@ItemName, @FoundAt, @TimeIn, @ImageName, @ContentType, @Data);SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
                        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
                        {
                            cmd.Connection = con;
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemName", ItemName);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FoundAt", Place);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeIn", DateTime.Now);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageName", imageName);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContentType", "image/png");
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", bytes);
                            con.Open();

                            Session["CapturedImageId"] = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

                            con.Close();

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static byte[] ConvertHexToBytes(string hex)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[hex.Length / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < hex.Length; i += 2)
        {
            bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);
        }
        return bytes;
    }

    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public static string GetCapturedImage()
    {
        string url = string.Empty;
        int imageId = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["CapturedImageId"]);
        string VisitorManagementConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["VisitorManagementConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(VisitorManagementConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Data FROM LostFound WHERE Id = @Id";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", imageId);
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                byte[] bytes = (byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                url = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        HttpContext.Current.Session["CapturedImageId"] = null;
        return url;
    }
    protected void btnCapture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

}
```

The values form the textbox never inserted into the database. only
datetime.now, imageName, contentType and data can be inserted.
should the insert textbox query at btncapture?

Can someone guide me where am I going wrong?

Comment: Could you share the stored procedure? The problem may there.

Comment: ItemName and Place look like keywords change it to different name and check

Comment: @smoksnes i have copy paste all the code

Comment: Did you solve it yet? If not **read both answers very carefully**. You need to move the code that saves to the database into a button click event. I see the additional code you posted in your question, you do realise there is nothing in the `protected void btnCapture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` event as @smoksnes demonstrated.

Answer (score 0):

This code should *at least* be in a button click.

By the time the page_load event is called in the [asp.net page event life cycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) the TextBoxes will have been cleared.

Answer (score 0):

You're only submitting to DB if it's *not a postback*.

```
if (!this.IsPostBack)
```

Since you're only running this in `Page_Load`, the textfields will probably not have any user inputs, and is therefore blank. Either you can do it on PostBack.

```
if (this.IsPostBack)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

Or, even better, do as **Jeremy Thompson** suggested and assign an event handler when the user clicks a button. Doing this kind of logic in `Page_Load` often come back and haunt you later. What happens when some other developer adds an `UpdatePanel`, or another postback event? Then this code will run at **every** postback. It will not scale very good. It seems as you already got an event handler for this - `btnCapture_Click`, I suggest that you use it.

Example:

In your HTML:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="btnCapture_Click" Text="Button" />
```

And in your CS:

```
protected void btnCapture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.InputStream.Length > 0)
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream))
            {
                string hexString = Server.UrlEncode(reader.ReadToEnd());
                string imageName = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yy hh-mm-ss");
                string imagePath = string.Format("~/losefound/{0}.png", imageName);
                string ItemName = txtItemName.Text;
                string Place = txtPlace.Text;
                byte[] bytes = ConvertHexToBytes(hexString);
                File.WriteAllBytes(Server.MapPath(imagePath), bytes);
                string VisitorManagementConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["VisitorManagementConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(VisitorManagementConnectionString))
                {
                    string query = "INSERT INTO LostFound (ItemName, FoundAt, TimeIn, ImageName, ContentType, Data) VALUES(@ItemName, @FoundAt, @TimeIn, @ImageName, @ContentType, @Data);SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemName", ItemName);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FoundAt", Place);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeIn", DateTime.Now);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageName", imageName);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContentType", "image/png");
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", bytes);
                        con.Open();

                        Session["CapturedImageId"] = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

                        con.Close();

                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

If you're having trouble binding the button you can take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20798135/asp-net-button-not-firing-on-click-event).

First, check if you have `AutoEventWireup="true"` in the declaration of your aspx.

You can also try to manually assigning the delegate.

```
btnCapture += new EventHandler(btnCapture_Click);
```

Comment: If you use the debugger in Visual Studio. What's the value of `txtItemName.Text`?

Comment: Once i  debug straight way jump to postback it did not jump to button