# Why is IsPostBack skipping through my code?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, code-behind

I'm trying to decide using switch case which operation to take where ever section i choose to enter in the page, thus when posting back it will take the right action.

**This is the button** (Note, this is not the button i'm posting with, rather the one where i enter the section of editing credentials)

```
<input type="button" value="Edit credentials" onclick="ShowWindow('#EditDetails', 2500); <%WhatToDo = "ChangeUserInfo";%>" />
```

**Code-behind:**

```
public string WhatToDo = "";



protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

if (IsPostBack)
    {
        switch (WhatToDo)
        {
            case "ChangeUserInfo": ChangeUserInfo();
            break;
        }
    }

}

protected void ChangeUserInfo(){ something }
```

The posting seems to work, other than the fact that it doesn't run the switch case... 
don't know what to do and what am i doing wrong.. If anyone knows what am i doing wrong it'll be great :)

Comment: IsPostBack will be true when ever you do a post back, regardless of which button caused it. Your misunderstanding what it does, maybe [read this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Why are you doing it this way? I would guess that you come from a classic asp background? ASP.Net is event driven, so you just have to add a server side button with a click event.

Comment: [This is what you want to do](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15569857/asp-net-button-onclick-event-not-firing)

Comment: @Liam Yes, i am actually... this is a school project, and we haven't yet learned about server side buttons. However, is this not a possible way of doing it? If not, please show me an example of how i can do it :)

Comment: @Liam Ah, i see.... still i know nothing on how to work this button... can you show me an example with reference to my code and method name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You hook up events in ASP.Net, ASP.Net hides the request and response object for you and wraps it into an [Event Driven Architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming) . So you don't need to handle the button being pressed in the `Page_Load`. Instead you need:

[Server side](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side) button in the `.aspx`:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="cmdResubmit" OnClick="cmdAddBooking_Click" Text="Resubmit" />
```

and an event with the same name as the `OnClick` in the code behind:

```
protected void cmdAddBooking_Click(object sender, object e)
{
   //put code button code here
   SomeClass.value = 123;
   SomeClass.StringValue = "1234";
   //etc. etc.
}
```

notice the name of the method matches: `OnClick="cmdAddBooking_Click"` in the button!

That's it. If you want multiple buttons then add multiple `<asp:Button>` with multiple event attached to them.

**Note:**
Clicking a button **also** triggers a page load (and your event) so any code in the `Page_Load` event will run on every button click. You can avoid this by wrapping it in `if (IsPostBack)`, this means the code inside this `if` statement will only run on load not on postback

Comment: That's great! it works, and i also done it for another button to make the data loading only happen when i need it. However, one final question - how can i also set a public variable's value using this button? since i cannot use <% %> on an asp button?... You know... other than putting in inside the method...

Comment: I'm not sure I'm clear what your asking @YuvalRoth? If you mean set a property in some class then you can do this in the `cmdAddBooking_Click` method.

Comment: I mean, on a normal button I could put inside the onclick property this :   <% WhatToDo = "ChangeUserData" %>  which is a public string and i used it to keep track of things. actually when i think of it now, i don't need it if i use these asp buttons. however, just out of interest, how can i do it on an asp button?

Comment: It specifically says in the error, i cannot use <%%> on an asp button.

Comment: anything you put into a button on the client using print statement (`<%%>`) will not be available on the server side. `<%%>` is a print statement, you can't print into a server side button, only the HTML markup.