# My button on click is not working

Tags: html, asp.net

I have a registration page in that page I have a text box for mobile number and a button in my designing page but when I click on the submit button its not fire in the coding page where the method `button_click` define.

my **designing page**:

```
  <asp:Button ID="btnprocced1" class="btn btn-primary jk" runat="server" 
   Text="procced" OnClick="btnprocced1_Click" />
```

**code behind**:

```
protected void btnprocced1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ...
}
```

> **Note:** I'm using web user control so my question is How to generate
>   buttonclick event in `.ascx` page.

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: could you post your code, so we can help?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15569857/asp-net-button-onclick-event-not-firing

Comment: actually I am using it in user control page ascx . Is there any problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fire button click event using `.ascx` page then you'll first have to add following code in your code behind.

**.ascx** Code.

```
public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public event EventHandler buttonClick;
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        buttonClick(sender, e);
     }
 }
```

Then you can subscribe the event buttonClick at webpage to display the different information .

**.aspx.cs** Code.

```
 public partial class Test: System.Web.UI.Page
 {
      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         UserControlID.buttonClick+=new EventHandler(UserControlID_buttonClick);
      }

      protected void UserControlID_buttonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         Response.Write("Hey, ButtonClick Is Working Now.");
      }
  }
```

It would help to identify button click whenever it's triggered. Hope it helps.