# asp button on click event does not enter the onclick function c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net

I know there already exist a thread for the same question but it didn't help me fix it (I tried what they suggested) anyways here is the html side of the button, is there anything I'm missing:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnadd" runat="server" Text="add" OnClick="btnadd_Click" CausesValidation="False"/>
```

And this is the c# side:

```
protected void btnadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do something
}
```

EDIT: solution, i had the button inside a form causing it not to work, removed the form and it worked

Comment: I would guess the button is not posting back to server. Try adding AutoPostBack="True" to access server side methods.

Comment: Ryan Thomas where do i need to add it?

Comment: In your button declaration, it's an attribute, so just after CausesValidation should be fine.

Comment: did not work...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15569857/asp-net-button-onclick-event-not-firing

Comment: Could you give code with your form tag?