# asp button onclick not firing

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

I need your help! I am stuck here. I have a webform in which there is a dropdownlist and a button. But onClick function is not firing. I've test it with debugging and breakpoints.

> **What i've tried yet:**

- [asp.net Button OnClick event not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15569857/asp-net-button-onclick-event-not-firing)
- [Onclick not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669448/onclick-not-firing)

**Here is my Code of WebForm:**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/CTOAdmin.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AddCityArea.aspx.cs" ClientIDMode="Static" Inherits="E_Challan.AddCityArea" %><asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="inner_content" runat="server">

<div class="md-card">
            <div class="md-card-content">
                <div class="uk-grid" data-uk-grid-margin>
                    <div class="uk-width-medium-1-2">

                        <div id="form_validation" class="uk-form-stacked">
                            <center><h2>Add City Area</h2>
                            <div class="uk-form-row">
                                <label for="fullname">Select City<span class="req">*</span></label>
                                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="val_select" data-md-selectize>
                                    <asp:ListItem value="">Choose..</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem value="press">Press</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem value="net">Internet</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem value="mouth">Word of mouth</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem value="other">Other..</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </div>
                             <div class="uk-form-row">
                                <label for="fullname">City Name<span class="req">*</span></label>
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtsearch" ClientIDMode="Static" type="text" name="fullname" class="md-input" /><br /><br /><br />
                                 <br />
                                <div id="mymap" style="width:auto;height:400px" ></div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="uk-form-row">
                                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnAdd" class="md-btn md-btn-primary" Text="Add Area" OnClick="btnAdd_Click"></asp:Button>
                            </div></center>
                        </div>

                    </div>++
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<script  src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&v=3.exp&libraries=places"></script>
<script src="maps.js"></script>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

### Code Behind

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Web; 
using System.Web.UI; 
using System.Web.UI.WebControls; 
namespace E_Challan 
{ 
   public partial class AddCityArea : System.Web.UI.Page 
   { 
      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
      { 
      } 

      protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
      { 
         Label1.Text = txtsearch.Text.toString(); 
      } 
   }
}
```

I've another webform with same masterpage. On that webform my button click function is firing. But in that webform my onclick function is not firing.

Comment: Where is `onclick` in your code ?

Comment: It's been a while since my ASP.NET days, but last I checked, it only played nice with a page that has one runat="server" tag. Does your other (working) page have two runat="server" tags?

Comment: `protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label1.Text = txtsearch.Text.toString();
        }`

Comment: where is your <form> tag?

Comment: @g2000 - It's a content page, so `form` tag must be in the master page.

Comment: Yes <form> tag is in my master page. Is there my javascript is creating problem?

Comment: @KashifIjaz - Can you show a small piece of code behind? What you are doing in Javascript with button?

Comment: yes here is my code behind file code: `using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace E_Challan
{
    public partial class AddCityArea : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label1.Text = txtsearch.Text.toString();
        }
    }
}`

Comment: @KashifIjaz - You should edit your question and post your code. Anyways try deleting this method and go to your designer and double click the button to re-generate the handler.

Comment: select your button and check it's properties, switch to events and see click event is binded with some method or not?

Comment: After that can you look at the console and see if any js error is appearing/

Comment: @HaseebAsif - I've checked the properties. Everything is perfect. click event is binded.

Comment: @RahulSingh - I've re-created the event by double clicking on button and test again but nothing happens.

Comment: I've add breakpoint on pageload event but it is also not firing.

Comment: I've checked the console there is only 1 error that says maps.google.com api used multiple times.

Comment: console JS error seems culprit, which is stopping your other JS code (__postback) to run

Comment: I've fixed the JS error but still same issue :(

Comment: @KashifIjaz Remove everything (including js files) and keep Button control only. Then check Page_Load and btnAdd_Click are fired. Also remove **ClientIDMode="Static"** from  **page directive** which is not a good practice in ASP.Net Web Form.

Comment: I checked but nothing happens. I am going tp change my masterpage. I found the problem. Actually there are 2 <form> tags in my masterpage. But 1 form tag is parent in which runat=server is written and other form tag is child element. This element doesn't have any runat=server attribute. Form tag cannot be nested. So i think it is because of form tags. If i remove the child form element then my template crashes.